# Why does Haskell point free version of function result in ambiguous type error?

Tags: function, haskell, types, monomorphism-restriction

It turns out that in GHC 7.10, this compiles fine:

```
mysum xs = foldr (+) 0 xs
```

But this:

```
mysum    = foldr (+) 0
```

results in the following error:

```
No instance for (Foldable t0) arising from a use of ‘foldr’
The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
Relevant bindings include
  mysum :: t0 Integer -> Integer (bound at src/Main.hs:37:1)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Foldable (Either a) -- Defined in ‘Data.Foldable’
  instance Foldable Data.Functor.Identity.Identity
    -- Defined in ‘Data.Functor.Identity’
  instance Foldable Data.Proxy.Proxy -- Defined in ‘Data.Foldable’
  ...plus five others
In the expression: foldr (+) 0
In an equation for ‘mysum’: mysum = foldr (+) 0
```

Why does this happen, and what is the insight that's achieved by understanding this difference? Also, can I give this function a type (that's still generic) to make this error go away?

Comment: *The dreaded monomorphism restriction strikes again!*

Comment: I thought, in recent GHC the monomorphism restriction was turned off by default?

Comment: @arrowdodger, you missed a letter: in recent GHCi the monomorphism restriction is turned off by default.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the monomorphism restriction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496864/what-is-the-monomorphism-restriction)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As usual with cases where making a well-typed function point-free suddenly results in type errors about unfulfilled typeclass constraints, the ultimate cause of this is the [monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction), enabled by default.

You can solve this by either adding a type signature to `mysum`:

```
mysum :: (Foldable f, Num a) => f a -> a
```

or by turning off the monomorphism restriction:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
```

Comment: Here's an example of a related situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052670/

Comment: Sign ... monomorphism restriction. What a name.

Comment: @Ana: It sounds a lot scarier than it is, and it comes up *a lot*. And no surprise: it's arbitrary and unnatural, so it's going to trip you up unless you know about it off-hand. That's why people like to call it the *dreaded* monomorphism restriction :).

Comment: I see the above error also in GHCi (version 8.4.4). Is the monomorphism restriction now enabled by default in GHCi?